# C# How Can i reload datagridview like first load form after search with reset button

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a few `TextBox`es and I use this code for textchange events to search:

```
DataView dvTelbook = dtTelbook.DefaultView;
dvTelbook.RowFilter = "[name] LIKE '%" + textBox.Text + "%'";
```

That code works well and when I use that `TextBox` to search in a `DataGridView` (filtered by name) it works so far.

My *problem* is:

When I click the reset button, the `DataGridView` can't reload.
I want to reload the `DataGridView` after search, exactly like when first loading the `Form`.

But `datagridview.refresh();` does not work and `datagridview.datasource = "null"` clears my `DataGridView`. And when I use
 `datagridview.datasource = mydata();` the `DataGridView` loads again but all data is duplicated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can clear the RowFilter.

Comment: How can do it ? after clear row filter . my form reload or not ?

Comment: Set it to null.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the duplication, do:

```
datagridview.datasource = "null"
```

followed by:

```
datagridview.datasource = mydata();
```

Comment: tnx dude . but when i use your code . data duplicate when datasource = mydata() run

Comment: The the source mydata() contains duplicates and has to be cleared before filling.

Comment: @stackover I understand what you mean now, myData().clear should work if it is a list which you are using as a datasource().

Comment: when i cleared the datagrdid with datasource = null and after that i use datasource = mydata();   and again duplicated . any solution ?

Comment: DanielFawcett : yeah dude i use access database . but i stuck in this problem . when i use null datasource . gridview cleared and when i use datasource = mydata(); after null command . my gridview duplicated .

Comment: @stackover it's because when you are making the datasource = null. all that does it make the data point to Null. It does not effect your data source directly. You need to Clear the actual data source it's self. because it is more than likely duplicated there.

Comment: @ DanielFawcett  :tnx for your explain . but can you send me the code ? i cant understand what should i do .  i use row but didnt work in my VS

Answer (score 0):

i find solution .

see my reset form code :

```
      private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
        textBox5.Clear();
        textBox6.Clear();

             // this line work and clear my datagrid view
           dataGridView1.Columns.Clear(); 
              //this line cant work and my datagridview is blank                
            dataGridView1.DataSource = mydata();

    }
```

that code is wrong . 
i use this code as solution :

i use this
    private DataTable myname = new DataTable();
after that : i use `myname.Reset();` in button 3 click.

see button3 click code :

```
  textBox1.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
        textBox5.Clear();
        textBox6.Clear();

          myname.Reset();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = mydata(); 
            DataView test = myname.DefaultView;
            test.RowFilter = string.Empty;
```

and done . 
my result refresh good and dont duplicated .

good luck